# Dual ASA5510 with dual ISP failover

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, redundancy, failover, dual-homed

I am setting up a highly redundant network and want to run my two ASA's in failover mode - each with a link to a router connected to two different ISP's.

The topology:

[image: Topology]

My two 2911's are running BGP to the ISPs, and the ASAs are configured in active/passive failover mode.

But how do I configure the links from the ASAs to the routers? They are on 2 different subnets at the moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming a single context active/passive failover configuration with the ASAs connecting to the 2911s on unique subnets, you could trunk the links using two subinterfaces and vlan tagging.  But the **hack** is to not have both subinterfaces active at the same time on a single ASA.  On the ASA on the left assuming it's active, the first subint would be alive and the second down.  After a failover event, the ASA on the right becomes active, and the first subint goes down and the second subint comes up.

> Ideally, the ASAs share a common subnet with the LAN side of the
>   2911s precluding this hack; a L2 switch can sit between the ASAs and provide connectivity
>   from any ASA to any 2911.

---

*Only the relevant subinterfaces' config shown.*

**ASA**

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.10
 vlan 10
 nameif Outside-ISP1
 security-level 0
 ip address 1.1.1.254 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.11
 vlan 11
 nameif Outside-ISP2
 security-level 0
 ip address 2.1.1.254 255.255.255.0

route Outside-ISP1 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 1.1.1.1 1
route Outside-ISP2 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 2.1.1.2 1
```

**2911-ISP1**

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 description LAN
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.10
 description LAN-ISP1
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip vrf forwarding vpn
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.11
 description LAN-ISP2
 encapsulation dot1Q 11
 ip address 2.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
 shutdown
```

**2911-ISP2**

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 description LAN
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.10
 description LAN-ISP1
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 1.1.1.2 255.255.255.0
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.11
 description LAN-ISP2
 encapsulation dot1Q 11
 ip address 2.1.1.2 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I think we will go with the ideal solution with a common subnet on the links between the ASAs and the 2911's with a L2 switch in between.

Answer (score 2):

The current answer provides you with a good solution. However, I would advise against using a single switch to connect all of these devices. If you do this you end up with an additional failure domain with a single point of failure. I see two options here:

Use a switch stack to implement this recommendation. (Eliminates the single point of failure)

Directly connect links from each 2911 to each ASA. (Depends on port utilization)

I would also recommend enabling an IGP such as OSPF or EIGRP between your 2911 and ASA devices. If you are going to use static routes make sure that you implement the appropriate tracking configuration. The switch/es would mask link down thus preventing the route from being removed on the ASA. You could also implement HSRP on the 2911 routers and point the ASA 0.0.0.0/0 to the HSRP address.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot put 2 default route on ASA

```
ciscoasa(config)# route Outside-ISP1 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 1.1.1.1
ciscoasa(config)#
ciscoasa(config)#
ciscoasa(config)# route Outside-ISP2 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 2.1.1.2
ERROR: Cannot add route entry, conflict with existing routes
```

you can use 1 default and and others specific rote to other isp